# How to loop through a file of strings and load the string into a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

How can I loop through a file of strings and load the strings into a numpy ndarray?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the use-case? Why do you want strings in a numpy array? More explanation in your question will lead to more relevant answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a numpy vector of strings with a line per cell:

```
import numpy as np

with open("file.ext") as f:
    a = np.array(f.readlines())
```

This could be modified for, say, a file of floating-point space-separated values:

```
import numpy as np

with open("file.ext") as f:
    a = np.array([map(float, line.split()) for line in f])
```

Let's break down the argument to `array()` to clarify what's going on here.

- `[line for line in f]` would be equivalent to `f.readlines()` - it
  creates a list of strings, one per line in `f`.
- `[line.split() for line in f]` makes a 2D list of strings. Each line in `f` gets `split`
  at the spaces into a list of strings.
- Numpy's designed to deal with numeric values, though, not strings. So we need to turn each sublist of strings into a list of floats. `map` applies the same function to every element of a list (`float` in this case), so `map(float, line.split())` will turn a list of strings into a list of floats.
- So `[map(float, line.split()) for line in f]` creates a list of lists of floats - one list per line, where the floats have been split up at the spaces. This then gets sent to `array()` which knows how to deal with a list of lists.

Also look into the [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) family of Numpy functions.

Comment: Why map(float and not map(string?

Comment: @Superdooperhero - `line.split()` turns a string (`line`) into a list of strings. We need to turn this list of strings into a list of floats (using `map`) so that Numpy can deal with them. Numpy's not really designed to handle arrays of strings.